# Late '80s / early '90s urban sci-fi book where the protagonists discover other universes

Tags: story-identification, books, parallel-universe

I'm trying to remember the name of a sci/fi book from the late 80's/early 90's where the protagonists lived in a modern setting. They discover a way to travel to different universes but are left in a cliffhanger at the end of the book. The families get separated and one group ends up in a futuristic universe, gets captured by pirates of some sort, and sold into slavery. The last sentences are something along the lines of "and rescue never came".

Comment: Hi Jeff. This sounds like a young adult book. Can you remember if it was?

Comment: It's possible but I'm not 100% sure. It was a pretty upbeat book up until the harsh ending.

Comment: That sounds kind of like the "merchant princes" series by Charles Stross. I haven't read them, so I can't be sure.

Comment: This would have come out well before 2004 but thanks for the guess!